# Remove duplicate sub-strings in R

Tags: r, string, duplicates, tidyverse

I have string sequences of "BY","SN","SY" and "BN"
There are multiple instance as seen in the table below.
I want to reduce "SNSNSNBY" to "SNBY" and "SNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNBYSN" to "SNBY"

```
   SNo Bars                                                 
    <dbl> <chr>                                                       
 1      1 SNSNSNBY                                                    
 2      2 SNBYSN                                                      
 3      3 BYSN                                                        
 4      4 SNBY                                                        
 5      5 SNBY                                                        
 6      6 SNBY                                                        
 7      7 BYBYSNSN                                                    
 8      8 SNBY                                                        
 9      9 BYSN                                                        
10     10 BYSN                                                        
11     11 BYSN                                                        
12     12 SNBY                                                        
13     13 SNBY                                                        
14     14 BNSY                                                        
15     15 SNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNBYSN
16     16 SYBN                                                        
17     17 BNSYBN                                                      
18     18 BNSYBNSYBNSNBNBNBNBN                                        
19     19 SNBYSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSN      
20     20 BYSN
```

Comment: The final output should be a string "BNSY" or "SNBY" or "BYSN" or "SYBN"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to approach this is to `strsplit()` every second character then find the unique sequences and `paste()`.

**Code**

```
# Add a whitespace every 2 characters and then split into substrings
tmp1 <- strsplit(gsub("(.{2})", "\\1 ", df$Bars), " ")

# Obtain the unique substrings and paste
df$Bars <- sapply(tmp1, function(x){
  paste0(unique(x), collapse = "")
})

df

#    SNo     Bars
# 1    1     SNBY
# 2    2     SNBY
# 3    3     BYSN
# 4    4     SNBY
# 5    5     SNBY
# 6    6     SNBY
# 7    7     BYSN
# 8    8     SNBY
# 9    9     BYSN
# 10  10     BYSN
# 11  11     BYSN
# 12  12     SNBY
# 13  13     SNBY
# 14  14     BNSY
# 15  15     SNBY
# 16  16     SYBN
# 17  17     BNSY
# 18  18 BYSYBNSN
# 19  19     SNBY
# 20  20     BYSN
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = " SNo Bars 
 1      1 SNSNSNBY                                                    
 2      2 SNBYSN                                                      
 3      3 BYSN                                                        
 4      4 SNBY                                                        
 5      5 SNBY                                                        
 6      6 SNBY                                                        
 7      7 BYBYSNSN                                                    
 8      8 SNBY                                                        
 9      9 BYSN                                                        
10     10 BYSN                                                        
11     11 BYSN                                                        
12     12 SNBY                                                        
13     13 SNBY                                                        
14     14 BNSY                                                        
15     15 SNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNBYSN
16     16 SYBN                                                        
17     17 BNSYBN                                                      
18     18 BYSYBNSNBNSNBNBNBNBN                                        
19     19 SNBYSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSN      
20     20 BYSN", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: The final output should be a string "BNSY" or "SNBY" or "BYSN" or "SYBN"

Comment: @Shoonya this does not make sense for entry 18 since you specified 4 different substrings and this entry includes all of them. Please update your question adding a thorough explanaiton and the desired output for your mock `data.frame()`.

Comment: edited the data - some error in 18th row.

Answer (score 1):

One handy solution is to use str_replace_all() function from tidyverse core library stringr :

```
table<- table %>%
    mutate(Bars=str_replace_all(Bars, c("SNSNSNBY"="SNBY", 
    "SNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNBYSN"="SNBY"))
```

Comment: The final output should be a string "BNSY" or "SNBY" or "BYSN" or "SYBN"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when()`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(V3 = case_when(V3 == "SNSNSNBY" ~ "SNBY",
                        V3 == "SNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNSNBYSN" ~ "SNBY",
                        TRUE ~ V3)
         )
```

[image]